# WordPress: Update Post Category from single.php in a dropdown

Tags: wordpress, categories, frontend

I am building a HelpDesk system and I need the ability to update a category from the post page on the front end (single.php).  I have the following code: http://snipt.org/tlnmg1.  Everything works on submitting the posts from the front end, but after googling for hours, I'm at a standstill.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you explain "update a category" ? Also, what doesn't work? Thx.

Comment: When the post is created from the front end, it is automatically posted in the category "New Ticket."  I need to be able to change that category (i.e. Status) to something else from either single.php or another page template.  I have a code in place that I have cobbled together from some resources online, but I am missing something.  When the "update status" submit button is clicked, nothing happens.  I have updated the code snippet with the full code from single.php below.  Thanks! http://snipt.org/tlpz4

Comment: Does it reflect the change if you refresh the page?

Comment: No, so obviously nothing is being put into the database.  There is a disconnect somewhere.  After looking I"m still not sure.  It might also help to let you know that I am not exactly stellar at PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there are a number of issues that I see, right off the bat.

First, you have a set of form fields that are generated but when you hit submit... where does it go?  I don't see an actual  start tag, which needs an action="target" attribute.  The target should do the backend processing to actually post the page.

As for the categories, do you need the user to be able to create categories, or just change from a predefined list?  The list can be populated by a call to get_categories() (I think that is the name of the function) and iterating through what it returns and adding that to a drop down list.

Finally, the HUGE issue I see with this is lack of security and other measures...  You are opening yourself up to a world of hurt if you are trying to assemble this with copy/paste code.

Have you considered just using a bugtracker system or some sort of open source helpdesk stuff instead of wordpress?

You have drifted far afield of the intended purpose of the software.